# AES-128 CFB8 Encryption in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm working on a .Net Core 3.1 application that need to use AES-128 CFB8 encryption. I cannot seem to find a library for this. Do you have any recommendations?

The built-in library does not support CFB mode in .Net Core ("Specified cipher mode is not valid for this algorithm").
I have also tried to use Chilkat, but they do not allow me to use CFB8 (there is no way to set the amount of feedback bits to be used, and the default appears to be wrong).

My application must be able to run on Linux.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/38211

Comment: Hmm, seems like bartonjs kind of over-reviewed it, if that's a thing. Bouncy Castle is often used when the mode of operation / cipher is missing in the standard runtimes.